# Using underscore.js to find unique values based on dual properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Using Underscore.js, I'm trying to get unique values in an array that looks like this:

```
var links = [
    {source: 0, target: 1},
    {source: 0, target: 2},
    {source: 0, target: 3},
    {source: 0, target: 4},
    {source: 0, target: 1},
    {source: 4, target: 0}
];
```

so that it ends up like this:

```
var links = [
    {source: 0, target: 1},
    {source: 0, target: 2},
    {source: 0, target: 3},
    {source: 0, target: 4},
];
```

I want to get rid of links that have the same source & target pair in the same order (0,1 == 0,1) of course, but also want to get rid of those that are the same but inverted (0,4 == 4,0).

I'm sure I can do it with a double-nested _.map() but wanted to see if any Underscore magicians out there had a cleaner, more proper solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `_.uniq` is the answer.

```
uniq_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee])
```

[More info](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)

I believe you can use the third argument (`iteratee`) to provide a custom transformation function to be applied first before the comparisons.

Example using _.uniq (http://jsfiddle.net/muto6zs1/):

```
function(item) {
  // sort array of source and target and join it into a delimited string for a unique value
  return [item.source, item.target].sort().join(',');
}
```

Comment: If you are not going to provide an example, you could also list include the signature of the method.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the tip, just started using SO :)

Comment: Apparently I cannot type. I meant "you could at least include...". But you understood my either way :) Thanks for updating!

Comment: I tried _.uniq() and couldn't get the right output. How can you tell it to compare the current index's target with the previous' source (and vice-versa)? That's where I get stuck.

Comment: @jcnesci, you can't and should avoid in unique. Instead think of coming up with a unique constraint for the item in the array and return that in the iteratee

Comment: @cbayram that's really interesting, you're making me think about it in a whole new way! Thanks for expanding my coding mind. Exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten an answer using underscore, but to help you understand what goes on behind the scenes I've provided a JavaScript example:

```js
var links = [
    {source: 0, target: 1},
    {source: 0, target: 2},
    {source: 0, target: 3},
    {source: 0, target: 4},
    {source: 0, target: 1},
    {source: 4, target: 0}
];

// create a temporary buffer to hold unique keys
var keys = {};
links.forEach(function(item, index) {
  // this is the essential part of the uniqueness test
  var item = [item.source, item.target].sort();

  if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      keys[item] = index;
  }
});

// iterate over the unique keys and reconstruct a new array
links = Object.keys(keys).reduce(function(prev, index) {
  prev.push(links[keys[index]]);
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(links);
```

Comment: Wow, this method is pretty economical, especially when, by playing with it, it seems I only really need the keys array to get the answer. (If you do something like "keys[index] = item;" in the forEach instead). Then I don't see why you need the reduce function. Or maybe I'm missing something. Either way, this is really neat, thanks for the added input!

Comment: @jcnesci The last reduce operation is to recreate the original objects that you had in `links`; the keys are just strings.